# Java Swing JComboBox/ Button edit parameters

Tags: java, button, combobox, items

I am quite new to working with GUI in Java. I was trying several things, for example, adding a new entry to a JComboBox or changing a JButtons caption using the following commands in the run method:

pwSelection.addItem("Name 1");

dec_btn.setText("Example");

protected JComboBox pwSelection = new JComboBox(contents);

Unfortunately, none of it shows any effect as soon as I start the program.
The layout was made with the IntelliJ GUI Form Creator.
It would be great if you could give me any tips or alternative approaches.

```
package PackMain;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Password {

    String[] contents = {"Name 1", "Name 2"};
    protected JTextField newAdress;
    protected JPanel panel1;
    protected JComboBox pwSelection = new JComboBox(contents); // ?
    protected JLabel title;
    protected JTextField pwOutput;
    protected JButton enc_btn;
    protected JButton dec_btn;

    public JFrame run(){
        JFrame mainFrame= new JFrame ("Password");
        mainFrame.setContentPane(new Password().panel1);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 200);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        pwSelection.addItem("Name 1");
        dec_btn.setText("Example");

        return mainFrame;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Password().run();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding any panel to the frame, also you didn't initialize any of the attributes...

```
package password;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Password extends JFrame{

String[] contents = {"Name 1", "Name 2"};
protected JTextField newAdress;
protected JPanel panel1, panel2; //2 panels for a more organized approach...
protected JComboBox  pwSelection;// ?
protected JTextField pwOutput;
protected JButton enc_btn;
protected JButton dec_btn;

public Password(){          //Constructor of the class, initialize stuff here...

    super("Shinny title");
    //1. Initialize all your atributtes...
    newAdress = new JTextField();
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    pwSelection = new JComboBox(contents);
    pwOutput= new JTextField();
    enc_btn = new JButton("First button");
    dec_btn = new JButton("Second Button");
    //Set layouts..
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));          
panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Add items to panel 1...
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Adress:"));  //A more simple aproach for creating a label...
    panel1.add(newAdress);
    panel1.add(pwSelection);
    panel1.add(enc_btn);
    panel1.add(dec_btn);
    panel1.add(pwOutput);
    //Add items of panel 1 to panel 2...
    panel2.add(panel1);
    add(panel2);

    setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);

    //Proper way of stop the application at closing...
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

//This is not necessary as everything should be implemented in the constructor.
/*
public JFrame run(){
    JFrame mainFrame= new JFrame ("Password");
    mainFrame.setContentPane(new Password().panel1);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 200);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    pwSelection.addItem("Name 1");
    dec_btn.setText("Example");

    setVisible(true);
    return mainFrame;
}
```

*/

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Initialize the constructor...
    Password ps = new Password();
}
```

}

This will give you an idea of how the GUI on java can be implemented.

Comment: What exactly is the point of creating two panels and later adding the first to the second? But thank you anyway, this works great and honestly seems like a more logical approach than mine :D

Comment: Mainly order. The panel 1 will be the one holding and giving order to the elements inside it, while the panel 2 will be the one that is directly added to the frame.

Comment: Also it's easier to switch between panels if you want to show antoher screen. Just remove first panel and add the new one to the panel 2. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

panel1 is never defined as a new JPanel(), so it's null, and all of your other components -- pwSelection, title, etc. -- have never been added to panel1.

Comment: Ok, I've added: protected JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(); and added panel1.add(...) for all components . But now the Frame shows no components anymore